# Magento Out of stock product SEO

Tags: magento, seo

I hope many of you gone through this issue/problem.

When we setup magento store with 1000 products. Each will hold a unique URL, and when its gets scraped by google(search engines) then the product always should be in-stock if not then magento store will return 404 page.

For example:

www.magestore/unique-url.html

This gets daily 100's of hits towards site even the product was **out of stock** and not able to view in store so its returning 404.

***Solution***

1. URL rewrite is the solution that's what am trying daily, but if the products getting out of date is really high and cant able to do rewrite means then in most of points loosing SEO hits which leads to 404.
2. If I enable Out of stock visibility true then the product list also included the out of stock items, but I don't need that,need only direct URL Access.

   Am sure, many of you could solved it, please tell me a way to show these products only on direct URL Access but not in the regular product list view page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Out Of stock visibility and have your extension redirect all out of stock items to wherever you redirecting those now

Comment: Enable Out Of stock visibility will show the out of stovk items in the list but it should not displayed for me, i need only direct URL access.

Comment: so modify your list to ignore out of stock items

Comment: How to redirect such products to custom url. This method does not work